# vb.net - Formatting a datetime column of a datatable to a yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm string

Tags: string, vb.net, datetime, date-conversion

I dont seem to be able to figure out what is wront in the code. Here is a screenshot to see the error message, the code, and the content of the variable.

and a bigger part of the code:

```
       For Each value As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
                    If value.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime") Then
                        dq = dq & value.ColumnName & " = '" & r2.Item(value.ColumnName).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & "' and "
                    End If

            Next
```

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Write Convert.ToDateTime(value.ColumnName).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), this will solve the issue.

Comment: @HardikShah thank you that seems to work... do you mind posting it as answer and explaining what is going on in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just compiles because you have Option Strict Off(no-go). You have to cast the Object returned from `r2.Item(value.ColumnName)` to a `Date`. This also fixes this issue, you can use `Field`:

```
r2.Field(Of Date)(value.ColumnName).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Since you are german, note that your format string might not give you what you expect but something like `2021.02.23 15:00:24`. If you want `2021/02/23 15:00:24` you need to use `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator)

Comment: thank you! its sort of working now.. the problem I have now is this: In the database its saved as `2021-02-08 15:00:24`. I read it, and put it in a datatable. when I iterate the datatable the datatable contains `2021-08-02 15:00:24` is there a way to specify the datetime format when passing the values to the datatable?

Comment: @sharkyenergy: A `datetime` in the database or `Date`(in VB.NET) don't have any format, they just have a value. When you want to display this value you can use `ToString` to give them a format, like you did in your code. But never store it as string in the database or convert it to string too early in your backend code. Do that right before you want to display it somewhere.

Comment: It is a dateTime in the database... the only conversion I do is the one you see here.. but somehow its inverting months and days.. as you see in the screenshot above, the r2 contains `#8/2/2021 ...etc#` this is february 8th... but once I convert it with the code you posted I get august 2nd...

Comment: @sharkyenergy: no, you are confusing what you see in the debugger window with what it actually means. The date-format is built-in to the debugger. In VB.NET the debugger window displays Dates in this format: `#M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM#`. So the first is the month. That's what i meant with my previous comment, a date has just a value, the format is applied by the GUI.